# #1064 - Você tem um erro de sintaxe no seu SQL próximo a 'DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci' na linha 1

Tags: mysql, syntax-error

Então pessoal, eu exportei um banco de dados da escola onde estudo só que eu exportei o banco de um mysql antigo então ele gero outro código xml para mim
e preciso importar ele para um mysql mais recente ele da esse erro 1046 tem alguma forma de rodar ele no mysql atual?como?

erro do código :

```
Erro

Análise estática:

1 1 erros foram encontrados durante a análise.

    Era esperado o nome da entidade. (near "DEFAULT CHARACTER SET" at position 31)

Query SQL:

CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;

Mensagem do MySQL: Documentação
#1064 - Você tem um erro de sintaxe no seu SQL próximo a 'DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci' na linha 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Faltou você colocar o nome da sua base de dados....

```
CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS MinhaDataBase DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;
```

Para rodar no seu MySQL mais atual basta só você dar um nome para o `DATABASE` que está criando.

Comment: cara desculpa eu pergunta a onde que vai isso eu não sei xml eu apenas exportei isso para fazer meu tcc eu nunca mexi com xml

Comment: @AdrianoRufino se você quer importar um XML que possui todo o SQL de criação, coloque o conteúdo do XML na pergunta para que possamos ajudar. Você poderia importar o XML e quando o seu gerenciador abrir o texto dele, você poderia editar na mão mesmo conforme mostrei em minha resposta